# Undefined control sequence for TikZ, issue with \drawfill

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

The other colored arcs work. Why does the blue arc line give a Ti*k*Z complaint?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5 ,cap = round, color = blue] 
\draw [ ultra thick, blue]   [- ] (-2,0)--( 2,0) ;  %x axis
\draw [ ultra thick, blue]  [-] ( ( 0,-2) --( 0,2)  % y axis  

     % PROBLEM HERE at \drawfill Why
 \drawfill [ ultra thick, blue, opacity= 0.5, fill= blue] (-2,0) arc ( 180: 270: 2 );
% error \draw [ultra thick, blue, opacity= 0.5, fill= blue  ]  ( -2,0) arc ( 180: 270: 2 ) ; 

 \draw [ ultra thick, blue, opacity= 0.5, fill= yellow  ]  (0,2) arc ( 90: 180: 2 ) ;  

 \draw [ ultra thick, blue, opacity= 0.5, fill= red  ]  (2,0) arc ( 0: 90: 2 ) ; 

 \draw [ ultra thick, blue, opacity= 0.5, fill= green  ]  (0,-2) arc ( 270: 360: 2 ) ; 
% label 4 corners
%%% labels  A  B C D 
\draw (  0,2) node[ above  ] {A};
\draw (  0,-2) node[ below  ] { C};  
\draw (  -2,0 ) node[ above  left ] { B};  
\draw (  2,0 ) node[ above right ] { D};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The other colored arcs work. Why the blue arc line gave a  TikZ complaint

Comment: The command before the line where you get the error does not end with a semicolon and there is a spurious `(`. Change `\draw [ ultra thick, blue]  [-] ( ( 0,-2) --( 0,2)`  to `\draw[ultra thick, blue] (0,-2) -- (0,2);`. Apart from that, Ti*k*Z only knows `\filldraw`, but not `\drawfill`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A small, off-topic variation of nice @Jasper Habicht answer (+1):

- defined coordinates with labels for coordinates
- defined style for fill of `arc`
- not used `fill opacity`

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5, ultra thick, color=blue,
                fa/.style = {fill=#1!50} % fill arc
                    ]
% label 4 corners
\coordinate[label=A]        (a) at ( 0,2);
\coordinate[label= left:B]  (b) at (-2,0);
\coordinate[label=below:C]  (c) at (0,-2);
\coordinate[label=right:D]  (d) at ( 2,0);
% linea
\draw   (b) -- (d)  % x axis
        (a) -- (c); % y axis
% filled areas
\draw[fa=yellow]    (a) arc (90:180:2);
\draw[fa=blue]      (b) arc (180:270:2);
\draw[fa=green]     (c) arc (270:360:2);
\draw[fa=red]       (d) arc (0:90:2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Inspired by @Qrrbrbirlbel comments below. Code is recent and shoerter:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5, ultra thick, color=blue,
                fa/.style = {fill=#1!50} % fill arc
                    ]
% label 4 corners
\coordinate[label=A]        (1) at ( 0,2);
\coordinate[label= left:B]  (2) at (-2,0);
\coordinate[label=below:C]  (3) at (0,-2);
\coordinate[label=right:D]  (4) at ( 2,0);
% linea
\draw   (2) -- (4)  % x axis
        (1) -- (3); % y axis
% filled areas
    \begin{scope}[radius=2, delta angle=90]
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in {yellow, blue, green, red}
\draw[fa=\i]    (\j) arc[start angle=\j*90];
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result is the same as at first MWE.

Comment: what is this fa/.style command?  How to use it?

Comment: @mark, as noted in code: define style of coloring arc. Instead it you can write `\draw[fill=yellow!50] ... `,  \draw[fill=blue!50] ...` using it apicture code is a wee bit shorter 

Comment: Speaking of off-topic, `(<start angle>:<end angle>:<radius>)` is considered deprecated ("only coordinates should use `(` and `)`") and `arc[start angle=<start angle>, end angle=<end angle>, radius=<radius>]` should be used. This would also allow to do `\begin{scope}[radius=2, delta angle=90] \draw … arc[start angle=90];\draw … arc[start angle=180];` and so on.

Answer (score 10):

You should make sure that every Ti*k*Z statement ends with a semicolon. Sometimes it is not clear from the error message directly on which line the semicolon is missing. Therefore, I would suggest that you apply certain spacing rules throughout your code, because this can help a lot in finding missing or spurious characters.

In this concrete case, the culprit was the line *before* the line where you assumed the error, since it did not end with a semicolon `;` and also had a spurious open parethesis `(`. Apart from  that, Ti*k*Z only knows a `\filldraw` macro, but not `\drawfill`. Anyways, since you already use `\draw[fill]` for the other arc segments, I would stick to this version as it has essentially the same meaning,

I am unsure what `[-]` was supposed to denote, so I deleted it from the below cleaner version of your code. Also, I would probably change `opacity` to `fill opactiy` because I guess you don't want the border of the arc segments transparent as well.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, cap=round, color=blue] 
\draw[ultra thick, blue] (-2,0) -- (2,0); % x axis
\draw[ultra thick, blue] (0,-2) -- (0,2); % y axis  

\draw[ultra thick, blue, fill opacity=0.5, fill=blue] (-2,0) arc (180:270:2); 
\draw[ultra thick, blue, fill opacity=0.5, fill=yellow] (0,2) arc (90:180:2);
\draw[ultra thick, blue, fill opacity=0.5, fill=red] (2,0) arc (0:90:2);
\draw[ultra thick, blue, fill opacity=0.5, fill=green] (0,-2) arc (270:360:2);

% label 4 corners
%%% labels A B C D 
\draw (0,2) node[above] {A};
\draw (0,-2) node[below] {C};  
\draw (-2,0) node[above left] {B};  
\draw (2,0) node[above right] {D};  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `-` is a shortcut for `arrows=-` and denotes that no arrowtips shall be drawn. Sure, that's the default but maybe OP played around with different arrow heads?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, maybe. What seemed a bit strange was the second pair of square brackets (which is okay but uncommon). Anyways, removing it contributes to the legibility of the code from my point of view.